# Django view not updating after changes in model

Tags: python, django

I am running into a problem with a Django project I am currently working on.

I have a view in which I create a model instance via a POST request:

```
class CreatePollView(View):
    template = "polls/create_poll.html"

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def post(self, request):
        question_text = request.POST['question']
        pub_date = now()
        new_question = Question(question_text=question_text, pub_date=pub_date)
        new_question.save()

        options_list = request.POST.getlist('options')
        for option in options_list:
            option_text = option
            new_option = Option(option_text=option_text, question=new_question)
            new_option.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:detail', args=(new_question.id,)))
```

This works fine. I can add the question and its options to the DB and see that it has been added in the admin. But when I then call my index.html, in which I list all the question objects, it doesn't update.

```
class IndexView(View):
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    context = {
        'question_list': questions,
    }

    def get(self, request):
        return HttpResponse(self.template.render(self.context, request))
```

And the template:

```
{% extends 'homepage/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <h1>All Polls:</h1>
            <div>
                {% for question in question_list %}
                    <p><a href="{{ question.pk }}">{{ question }}</a></p>

                {% endfor %}
                <a href="new_poll" class="btn btn-primary">New Poll</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

When I build an error into the view, then fix it and run the code again it updates the list. `Question.objects.all()`

But other than that the model changes are not displayed here when I post a new model instance. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: This only seems to happen with class based views. When I was using method views it worked fine.

```
def index(request):
    question_list = Question.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = {
        'question_list': question_list,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))


def new_poll(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        question_text = request.POST['question']
        pub_date = now()
        new_question = Question(question_text=question_text, pub_date=pub_date)
        new_question.save()

        options_list = request.POST.getlist('options')
        # import pdb
        # pdb.set_trace()
        for option in options_list:
            option_text = option
            new_option = Option(option_text=option_text, question=new_question)
            new_option.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:detail', args=(new_question.id,)))
    else:
        template = loader.get_template('polls/create_poll.html')
        context = {
            'user': request.user
        }
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Comment: using generic class-based-views will allow you to write much less code than this.

Comment: I am in the middle of a refactor, and while this is nice, I first would like to figure out how to display the changes in my model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django is designed to work as a long running process (load once, serve forever), not as a CGI script where everything is reload on each and every HTTP request. This means that anything happening outside a function (ie at a module's top-level, in a class statement's body etc) is executed only once (per process) at module's first import (well, just as for any Python process actually - the point here is that it's a long running process, not a one-shot script).

So here:

```
class IndexView(View):
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    context = {
        'question_list': questions,
    }
```

Those three statements in your class body are eval'd with the `class` statement on your module's first import. From then those values won't be re-evaled for the process lifetime, so you indeed keep the same results for `context['question_list']` from request to request, until you kill your server process and start a new one (which will get stale after the first request, etc).

You don't have the problem with the function-based view because your code executed on each request, yielding an up to date queryset.

To make a long story short, start by moving this code into your class `get`  method:

```
class IndexView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
        questions = Question.objects.all()
        context = {
            'question_list': questions,
        }
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Then you may want to take a bit more time learning about django's [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/), [modelforms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/), [shortcuts](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/) etc, and if you insist on using class-based views then learn to use the [various mixins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/intro/#using-mixins) too.

Comment: Thank you very much! Good to learn this and now it works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpfull